# typescript error: would overwrite input file

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have updated [**latest Ionic version**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v3.3.0) and removed `src/declarations.d.ts` file.Now my app shows below error when I try to run the app `ionic serve`.

> typescript: /sophy/src/assets/dev-load/load.ts, line: 1
>               Module '../../../node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.js' was resolved to '/sophy/node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.js', but
>   '--allowJs' is not set.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import * as NProgress from '../../../node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.js'
>    L2:  (() => {
> ```

I [**have found the solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42867900/1077309) for it and now above error is not there.But now it shows below error.

> typescript error
>               Cannot write file '/sophy/node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.js' because it
>               would overwrite input file.

Do you know why?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

I think this is the issue here.So how can I solve it? When I remove the `declarations.d.ts` then above errors are coming.If I add it then no issues (I have to remove the `"allowJs": true` too).Any solution, please.

**src\assets\load.ts**

```
  import * as NProgress from '../../../node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.js'
    (() => {
      NProgress.start();
    })()
```

Comment: if it is the same nProgress , why not use [types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/nprogress) ?

Comment: Yes, same.Can you provide the answer how to do that? What changes should I do after installing the typings and etc? @suraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the type declarations for the js library.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/nProgress
```

The declaration file can be seen [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/nprogress/index.d.ts).
It will be added to `node_modules/@types` directory.
Do

```
 import Nprogress from 'nprogress'
```

Comment: I did it.But it shows this error on `import` line `[ts] File 'd:/sophy/node_modules/@types/nprogress/index.d.ts' is not a module.`.Why?

Comment: I have used like this `import * as NProgress from 'nProgress'`

Comment: Try import Nprogress from nprogress